# unloading code/modules

Tags: node.js

I'm curious if there is any good way to unload a module after using it.  I have some cases where I need to use modules that bring in a lot of code, but they are used rarely (say as an admin tool), but I hesitate to use them because afterwards they'll presumably just waste memory that could be better used elsewhere. Is there any way to unload them, either explicitly or by allowing the system to do so when they haven't been used for a while?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to access the module cache directly:

```
var name = require.resolve('moduleName');
delete require.cache[name];
```

Note that if your code carries a reference to whatever was exposed by these modules you want to get rid of, it won't be cleaned up.

(As an aside: Underneath the surface, `require.resolve` and `require.cache` are just proxies to `Module._resolveFilename` and `Module._cache` respectively, with `Module` being the core module loader, i.e. `require('module')`.)

Comment: This isn't a complete answer.  Some requires load an index.js file, which then load the real meat of the library.  

As an example, try 
require('async')
this loads "...async/lib/async.js", but also loads "..async/index.js", which you can see in the require.cache.  index.js is the parent of async.js.  So it's probably possible to unregister, but may require a recursive function to delete multiple modules.

Comment: Just do `for (var key in Object.keys(require.cache)) {delete require.cache[key];}`.

Comment: @Tower, That would unload all the modules. It might be better to try to check `module.parent` - or something - and only unload the modules you want to unload. For example, `util` and `fs` probably should not be unloaded.

Comment: Why should util and fs not be unloaded specifically?

Comment: Just a speculation though, I think most modules are stateless, usually if it requires any state the requiring module will have to invoke some constructor function like e.g. `bunyan.createLogger` to make a stateful instance. So I think unloading everything should generally not cause any problem for the majority of cases. (as simply requiring something should not by itself cause unrelated global state changes anyway)

Comment: This works particularly well if you're loading a JSON model/template, which you may need to use multiple times (as opposed to using a fs.readFile and subsequent JSON.parse)

Answer (score 8):

You can do something like this to "unload" a node module:

```
/**
 * Deletes a node module and all associated children
 * from node require cache
 * @param {string} moduleName The name of the module or 
 *                            absolute/relative path to it
 */
function deleteModule(moduleName) {
  var solvedName = require.resolve(moduleName),
    nodeModule = require.cache[solvedName];
  if (nodeModule) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nodeModule.children.length; i++) {
      var child = nodeModule.children[i];
      deleteModule(child.filename);
    }
    delete require.cache[solvedName];
  }
}
```

"Unloading" a node module means that you're "deleting" its entry from node require cache. The snippet above transitively deletes one node module from the cache and all the associated modules (children modules).

In my case I was requiring "index.js" that, at the same time, was requiring "/lib/.js". I wanted to test initialization of "index.js" (and therefore the only other module being required in there which was /lib/.js). Deleting "index.js" from the cache was not enough because the cache maintained a separate reference to "/lib/.js" and that caused the module "/lib/.js" to not be loaded again from its file.

The code above might certainly delete from the cache other modules this module depends on (this is actually what I wanted BUT you might not want to do this for other modules like "fs", "path" or even "underscore").

You can always extend this method to accept a list of modules you don't want to delete or a filter you could apply to the "path" of the resolved module. You can say: don't delete core node modules (a list of core node modules names is available as a npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-core-module-names) or don't delete any of the packages under node_modules, etc etc.. This could be a filter inside the function but it's the same logic.

Comment: This deleteModule function will run out of stack space on circular dependencies.