# Unloading module in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, require

Is it possible to unload modules in nodejs?
In other words: clear event listeners, timeouts, and intervals.

These modules are "sub-files" of my project, and i could overwrite the `.on()`, and `.once()`, but what about timeouts and intervals?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that it is possible to implement something that does this. This is related btw: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676612/unloading-code-modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not that I'm aware of.

You can remove all event listeners on an emitter by calling `myEmitter.removeAllListeners()`. As for clearing the timeouts and intervals, call `clearTimeout(timeoutName)` and `clearInterval(intervalName)` respectively.

Example:

```
var x = 0;
var myInterval = setInterval(function(){
  console.log('hello');
  if (x > 5) clearInterval(myInterval);
  x += 1;
},1000);
```

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: Wouldn't really work. The `modules` I'm talking about are kinda like `plugins`, and i want to be able to load (require), and unload the plugins without restarting the system.
I don't have a list of all the timeouts and intervals, and all the plugins listen to the same emitter. `removeAllListener` would remove all listeners for the other plugins too...  
Nice try though, ty.

Comment: You're going to have to show some code or be more specific. Your description of the problem isn't entirely clear. Each module and plugin should be self contained.... so why can't you implement like a `stop` method on them that clears events, intervals, timeouts, etc?