# Node.JS load module async

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, module, require

I would like to have the ability to load a module that has been changed. I would have to of course [unload the module first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6677355/463304). Since this is a webserver setup, I am asking if there is a way to load the module in an async fashion, to avoid freezing the webserver for the duration of the read of the updated file.

Awhile back Node.JS removed the `require.async` function. So, on the latest version of Node.JS, what would be the recommended alternative?

- Should I read the entire file first, and then use the `Module` library to parse the file contents. (as opposed to the default functionality of taking a file name to read and parse internally) How?
- Should I outsource this job to some open-source library? Which one?
- Should I write my own module handler - my own implementation of `requireAsync`? (I know how.)

<sub>Note: I do not want to do anything more than load a module async, so please do not recommend that I replace my setup with a new webserver routing framework.</sub>

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I posted this answer, but you are welcome to post an improvement.

See [the Node.JS source code](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/master/lib/module.js).

`Module.prototype.require = function(path) { return Module._load(path, this); };`

**Abridged version of `_load`**

```
Module._load = function(request, parent, isMain) {
  var filename = Module._resolveFilename(request, parent);
  if (Module._cache[filename]) return Module._cache[filename].exports;
  if (NativeModule.exists(filename)) {
    if (filename == 'repl') { // special case, needs the real require.
      var replModule = new Module('repl');
      replModule._compile(NativeModule.getSource('repl'), 'repl.js');
      NativeModule._cache.repl = replModule;
      return replModule.exports;
    }
    return NativeModule.require(filename);
  }
  var module = new Module(filename, parent);
  if (isMain) process.mainModule = module, module.id = '.';
  Module._cache[filename] = module;
  var hadException = true;
  try {
    module.load(filename);
    hadException = false;
  } finally {
    if (hadException) delete Module._cache[filename];
  }
  return module.exports;
};
```

**My version of `require.async.js` will be something like**

```
var NativeModule = require('native_module');
var fs = require('fs');
if(!require.async) require.async = function (path, callback) { module.exports(path, this, callback); } // Comment out if you dislike using globals
module.exports = function(request, parent, callback) {
  var filename = Module.resolve(request, parent); // This is a Sync function. TODO, change it to an async function with a callback.
  if (Module.cache[filename]) callback(Module.cache[filename].exports);
  else if (NativeModule.exists(filename)) callback(new Error('What are you thinking?'))
  else fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function(err, file) {
    if (Module.cache[filename]) callback(null, Module.cache[filename].exports); // For the case when there are two calls to require.async at a time.
    else if(err) callback(err)
    else {
      var module = new Module(filename, parent);
      try {
        module._compile(file);
        Module.cache[filename] = module;
      } catch(ex) {
        callback(err)
      }
      if(Module.cache[filename]) callback(null, module.exports)
    }
}
```

**Caveats**

- There is one TODO in the code which is to make the multiple calls to `stat` to be async. The actual reading of the file is regular async, so that is good.
- If you are async loading a module, and that module you are loading is sync loading another module, then you have not fully gone async with your code - have you.
- It uses one private method - `_compile`.

Comment: Is there a way to make that compile step async? I'm working on an embedded system. Lazy loading has made things better, but if I need to require a module for an api, all requests block while that module loads. Bad. News. Bears. y'know?

Comment: I've been reading the file, and using `vm.runInNewContext`, which is the same thing compile does. So it doesn't get loaded as a module, rather it is loaded by me and I use `vm` to run it. I have to do my own caching, but it does have the advantage of being able to reload a module.

Comment: Cool. I may need to use caching tricks for hotloading. I dug a little deeper and found that it isn't currently possible to async load scripts  https://github.com/iojs/io.js/issues/1083.