# Node.js - asynchronous module loading

Tags: javascript, node.js

Is it possible to load a Node.js module asynchronously?

This is the standard code:

```
var foo = require("./foo.js"); // waiting for I/O
foo.bar();
```

But I would like to write something like this:

```
require("./foo.js", function(foo) {
    foo.bar();
});
// doing something else while the hard drive is crunching...
```

Is there a way how to do this? Or is there a good reason why callbacks in `require` aren't supported?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.JS load module async](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13917420/node-js-load-module-async)

Comment: What is your use case?  This would not be a typical use of loading modules.  If you have a lot of data to process, `require()` may not be the best option anyway.

Comment: Templating engine - the templates will be compiled to .js files (Node.js modules) and I would like to load them without blocking the event loop.

Comment: The typical pattern I've seen for this is to just have an exported function that does the initialization. That function, of course, can take a callback: var foo = require("./foo.js").foo(function(bar) {..});

Comment: @MartinMajer how large are those templates anyway? The number of reqs/s when using `readFile` versus `readFileSync` when reading a 20K file for each request is pretty much the same for me. Have you tested the actual impact of using sync reads?

Comment: just compile them on server initialization. by the time you've connected to your db servers, they'll be compiled.

Comment: I'm working on an embedded device and this is *killing* me. Because it takes so long for v8 to parse and compile the JS, it turns out to be *really* slow to load apps.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

While `require` is synchronous, and Node.js does not provide an asynchronous variant out of the box, you can easily build one for yourself.

First of all, you need to create a module. In my example I am going to write a module that loads data asynchronously from the file system, but of course YMMV. So, first of all the old-fashioned, not wanted, synchronous approach:

```
var fs = require('fs');
var passwords = fs.readFileSync('/etc/passwd');

module.exports = passwords;
```

You can use this module as usual:

```
var passwords = require('./passwords');
```

Now, what you want to do is turn this into an asynchronous module. As you can not *delay* module.exports, what you do instead is instantly export a function that does the work asynchronously and calls you back once it is done. So you transform your module into:

```
var fs = require('fs');
module.exports = function (callback) {
  fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', function (err, data) {
    callback(err, data);
  });
};
```

Of course you can shorten this by directly providing the `callback` variable to the `readFile` call, but I wanted to make it explicit here for demonstration purposes.

Now when you require this module, at first, nothing happens, as you only get a reference to the asynchronous (anonymous) function. What you need to do is call it right away and provide another function as callback:

```
require('./passwords')(function (err, passwords) {
  // This code runs once the passwords have been loaded.
});
```

Using this approach you can, of course, turn any arbitrary synchronous module initialization to an asynchronous one. But the trick is always the same: Export a function, call it right from the `require` call and provide a callback that continues execution once the asynchronous code has been run.

Please note that for some people

```
require('...')(function () { ... });
```

may look confusing. Hence it *may* be better (although this depends on your actual scenario) to export an object with an asynchronous `initialize` function or something like that:

```
var fs = require('fs');
module.exports = {
  initialize: function (callback) {
    fs.readFile('/etc/passwd', function (err, data) {
      callback(err, data);
    });
  }
};
```

You can then use this module by using

```
require('./passwords').initialize(function (err, passwords) {
  // ...
});
```

which may be slightly better readable.

Of course you can also use promises or any other asynchronous mechanism which makes your syntax look nicer, but in the end, it (internally) always comes down to the pattern I just described here. Basically, promises & co. are nothing but syntactic sugar over callbacks.

Once you build your modules like this, you can even build a `requireAsync` function that works like you initially suggested in your question. All you have to do is stick with a name for the initialization function, such as `initialize`. Then you can do:

```
var requireAsync = function (module, callback) {
  require(module).initialize(callback);
};

requireAsync('./passwords', function (err, passwords) {
  // ...
});
```

Please note, that, of course, *loading* the module will still be synchronous due to the limitations of the `require` function, but all the rest will be asynchronous as you wish.

One final note: If you want to actually make *loading* modules asynchronous, you *could* implement a function that uses `fs.readFile` to asynchronously load a file, and then run it through an `eval` call to actually execute the module, but I'd **highly** recommend against this: One the one hand, you lose all the convenience features of `request` such as caching & co., on the other hand you'll have to deal with `eval` - and as we all know, *eval is evil*. So don't do it.

Nevertheless, if you *still* want to do it, basically it works like this:

```
var requireAsync = function (module, callback) {
  fs.readFile(module, { encoding: 'utf8' }, function (err, data) {
    var module = {
      exports: {}
    };
    var code = '(function (module) {' + data + '})(module)';
    eval(code);
    callback(null, module);
  });
};
```

Please note that this code is not "nice", and that it lacks any error handling, and any other capabilities of the original `require` function, but basically, it fulfills your demand of being able to asynchronously load synchronously designed modules.

Anyway, you can use this function with a module like

```
module.exports = 'foo';
```

and load it using:

```
requireAsync('./foo.js', function (err, module) {
  console.log(module.exports); // => 'foo'
});
```

Of course you can export anything else as well. Maybe, to be compatible with the original `require` function, it may be better to run

```
callback(null, module.exports);
```

as last line of your `requireAsync` function, as then you have direct access to the `exports` object (which is the string `foo` in this case). Due to the fact that you wrap the loaded code inside of an immediately executed function, everything in this module stays private, and the only interface to the outer world is the `module` object you pass in.

Of course one can argue that this usage of `evil` is not the best idea in the world, as it opens up security holes and so on - but if you `require` a module, you basically do nothing else, anyway, than `eval`-uating it. The point is: If you don't trust the code, `eval` is the same bad idea as `require`. Hence in this special case, it might be fine.

If you are using strict mode, `eval` is no good for you, and you need to go with the `vm` module and use its `runInNewContext` function. Then, the solution looks like:

```
var requireAsync = function (module, callback) {
  fs.readFile(module, { encoding: 'utf8' }, function (err, data) {
    var sandbox = {
      module: {
        exports: {}
      }
    };
    var code = '(function (module) {' + data + '})(module)';
    vm.runInNewContext(code, sandbox);
    callback(null, sandbox.module.exports); // or sandbox.module…
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks. But what I'd like to implement is exactly this: "Please note, that, of course, loading the module will still be synchronous due to the limitations of the `require` function, but all the rest will be asynchronous as you wish." I was trying some dirty tricks with the `vm` module (unstable) or private function `module._compile()`, but I wasn't able to produce a working solution.

I would just like to use some kind of `require` function, which wouldn't contain the `fs.readFileSync()` call for loading the module source code.

Comment: Thanks. I'll to replace `eval` with `vm.runInThisContext` (I use ES5/Strict, so no `eval`) and see if I can get it working...

Comment: The problem with `vm.runInThisContext` will (IMHO) be that you are not able to access local scope, which is required to modify the `module` variable. But `vm.runInNewContext` should do what you want: You specify the code as first parameter, and the `module` object as second parameter (the [documentation](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html#vm_vm_runinnewcontext_code_sandbox_filename) calls this `sandbox`. Then it should work.

Comment: I tried your `requireAsync` method and it works only if the module doesn't require any other modules (the paths to the other modules are not resolved correctly for some reason). Anyway, I can add the other modules I need straight to the sandbox. It might not be an universal solution, but it works for me, so thanks :-)

Comment: You're basically right, that the solution is not *perfect*, but hey, I sketched it up from 0 to 100 in 15 minutes or so ;-). However, you're welcome, and I'm glad I could help you :-). If you want to, I'd be happy if you could mark my answer as *answer* :-).

Comment: Thank you for this answer and clarification! It proves that my effort of making a exported db module which i require in my node project is correct, ...even though it looks a bit clumsy when requiring with a callback!

Comment: Also note you're injection of the global module is also missing other globals injected into your async loaded module. Such as ```(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) {``` In my opinion. Just don't do this its going to cause problems. Work around it. Live with the fact its loaded sync and wait until the time this is added into node core. I have no idea if its going to be added.

Answer (score 4):

The npm module [async-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/async-require) can help you to do this.

#### Install

```bash
npm install --save async-require
```

#### Usage

```js
var asyncRequire = require('async-require');

// Load script myModule.js 
asyncRequire('myModule').then(function (module) {
    // module has been exported and can be used here
    // ...
});
```

The module uses `vm.runInNewContext()`, a technique discussed in the accepted answer.  It has bluebird as a dependency.

*(This solution appeared in [an earlier answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20315434/node-js-asynchronous-module-loading#31071958) but that was deleted by review.)*

Answer (score 3):

Yes - export function accepting callback or maybe even export full featured promise object.

```
// foo.js + callback:
module.exports = function(cb) {
   setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('module loaded!');
      var fooAsyncImpl = {};
      // add methods, for example from db lookup results
      fooAsyncImpl.bar = console.log.bind(console);
      cb(null, fooAsyncImpl);
   }, 1000);
}

// usage
require("./foo.js")(function(foo) {
    foo.bar();
});

// foo.js + promise
var Promise = require('bluebird');
module.exports = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
   // async code here;
});

// using foo + promises
require("./foo.js").then(function(foo) {
    foo.bar();
});
```

Comment: None of them work. `TypeError: object is not a function` or `TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'then'
`.

Comment: It's not something built in. You need to construct promise object and assign it to `module.exports` in your module. (Or assign function to module.exports). I'll update answer with example if this is still not clear

Comment: Just be explicit about it next time... me or someone else might understand these shortcuts but most folks - especially starters - would not.

Comment: This worked for me, but small error in your code. The //usage part should be **require("./foo.js")(function(*err,* foo)** and not **require("./foo.js")(function(foo)** without the first argument *err*. That's why martin majer above was getting the type error.

Answer (score 2):

Andrey's code below is the simplest answer which works, but his had a small mistake so I'm posting the correction here as answer. Also, I'm just using callbacks, not bluebird / promises like Andrey's code.

```
/* 1. Create a module that does the async operation - request etc */

// foo.js + callback:
module.exports = function(cb) {
   setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('module loaded!');
      var foo = {};
      // add methods, for example from db lookup results
      foo.bar = function(test){
          console.log('foo.bar() executed with ' + test);
      };
      cb(null, foo);

   }, 1000);
}

/* 2. From another module you can require the first module and specify your callback function */

// usage
require("./foo.js")(function(err, foo) {
    foo.bar('It Works!');
});

/* 3. You can also pass in arguments from the invoking function that can be utilised by the module - e.g the "It Works!" argument */
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who uses `ESM` modules and top level `await`, this will just work out of the box without using callbacks to `commonJS` `require` or installing any packages like `async-require`.

```js
// In foo.mjs
await doIOstuffHere();
export foo;

// in bar.mjs
import foo from "./foo.mjs";
foo.bar(); // this function would not run till the async work in foo.mjs is finished
```