# Incomplete data using request.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

I'm using request.js to download the content of a web page, but I need to wait until the dom is completely loaded before using it. Here is my code:

```
function requestPage(id) {
var options = {
    method: 'GET',
    gzip: true,
    url: 'xxx' + id,
    headers: getHeaders
}

request(options, function(error, response, body) {
    if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        generatePDF(generateHTML(body, id),id)
    }
})
}
```

How can I wait until everything is loaded before using the response in my generateHtml function?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [wait-for-request-to-finish-node-js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30389764/wait-for-request-to-finish-node-js)

Comment: do you want to turn w website into a pdf? in case you do, check this out http://phantomjs.org/screen-capture.html

Comment: well I'm already using PhantomJS to convert to PDF. My probleme is the fetching part.