# require function not working in Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to include modules in my nodejs application. The problem I'm facing is the code snippet below:

```
let adapter = new Adapter().then(function(result){
        let test= require('./loader');
        console.log(test);
}).catch(function(){});
```

Results always returned

```
{}
```

File loader.js

```
module.exports = {
   load_controller: () =>
   {
   }
};
```

Pls help me ^^

Comment: What do you expect that to do? Why?

Comment: require modules are synchronous and it should work as written. try changing your code instead of focusing on require? see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20315434/node-js-asynchronous-module-loading

Comment: Why you call `require` inside of `then`, and not before?

Answer (score 0):

`require` in node is synchronous.

Assuming you have a good reason to asynchronously load your module, [this answer details how to do it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20528452/2872479).  The tl;dr is to export a function that takes the callback of what you would like to do async.

Unless your code in `./loader` actually depends on the `new Adapter()` being initialized first, then this isn't necessary.