# Require statement inside an if runs even if it returns false

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack

I have added a require statement to require the `ws` library inside an if statement so that it will be imported only if its not the browser. For example, require `ws` only for the tests.

```
if (!process.browser) {
  webSocketLinkConfig.webSocketImpl = require('ws');
}
```

But the problem is, even though the rest of the assignment `webSocketLinkConfig.webSocketImpl` doesn't happen, the require gets executed and I get a warning in the browser saying `Module not found: Can't resolve 'bufferutil' in '/Users/pubudu/Projects/FleetManager/fm-dash-front/node_modules/ws/lib'`

Any idea what's happening and how to fix it?

This is a `react` app built with `create-react-app`.

Comment: Hi maybe this thread can help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20315434/node-js-asynchronous-module-loading

Comment: Are there chances you don't have process.browser set? It is specific to your build, which wasn't shown in the question.

Comment: @estus It has been set correctly but still gets the issue. If I add some code inside that if block it won't get executed. But this require does.

Comment: Again, this is specific to how you build client side app, nothing else. The question doesn't contain necessary information.

Comment: @estus Ah sorry. It's a `react` app built with `create-react-app`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not used process.broswer before, so it may be possible you do not have it set. I made a sandbox for getting whether or not you are running in a browser by using `navigator`.

> The navigator object contains information about the browser. - [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/Jsref/obj_navigator.asp)

```
if (!navigator) {
  webSocketLinkConfig.webSocketImpl = require('ws');
}
```

[Here is a CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/ll8r0088j9) which (using console) shows how you can use `navigator` to tell if you're running your code in a browser. Hope this helps.

Comment: `navigator` is not defined in Node, that will throw if run in node. you should check it navigator is present first, also, you can use `window` that isn't defined in node too.

Comment: Used navigator and window but both have the issue. Both return undefined in node and works on the browser. I don't think the problem is there.

Comment: Does checking for undefined instead work? i.e. if (navigator === undefined) { // do something } else { // do something else }