# Only first require add a file using jasmine from node

Tags: javascript, node.js, jasmine

I'm using grunt-jasmine-nodejs and I have 3 specs that require the same file:

I have code like this:

```
$.platform = $.platform || {};
console.log($.platform.formSupport);
require('../runtime/platform/js/modules/platform.formSupport.js');
console.log($.platform.formSupport);
```

each file that console.log before and after require that file and I get only one instance (after first require) and the rest return undefined. How can I load same file multiple times in different specs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by unloading the module

```
var name = require.resolve('../runtime/platform/js/modules/platform.formSupport.js');
delete require.cache[name];
```

found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6677355/387194)