# Is Node's require cache garbage collected?

Tags: node.js

NodeJS require function, that loads modules, has a "cache" (which is a object).

Entries is this cache are garbage collected once I'm no longer using the module? (resulting in loading from disk if used again)

*I think the answer is "no", but I didn't found any references on the web*

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Entries is this cache are garbage collected once I'm no longer using
>   the module?

No.  Modules loaded with `require()` are cached indefinitely whether you are done using them or not.

Memory for Javascript variables/objects that is used by the module is garbage collected subject to all the normal rules of garbage collection (when there is no live code that still has a reference to the variable/object).  But, the module cache keeps a reference to the loaded module itself so the code or any module level variables are not garbage collected unless a module is manually removed from the cache.

Here's a [link to the node.js doc](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_caching) on the topic.

> Caching
>
> Modules are cached after the first time they are loaded. This
>   means (among other things) that every call to require('foo') will get
>   exactly the same object returned, if it would resolve to the same
>   file.

If you want to manually remove a module from the cache, that is described here:

[unloading code/modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676612/unloading-code-modules)

Though, this will allow all module-level variables to be garbage collected, given the way node.js is structured I don't think it will actually unload the code from memory.