# Require and UnRequire a file dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, require, right-to-left

I am changing language dynamically, so I want to switch from rtl to ltr and vice-versa.

I am using bootstrap-rtl for rtl support.

Here is my code:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.isRTL !== nextProps.isRTL) {
      if (nextProps.isRTL) {
        require('bootstrap-rtl/dist/css/bootstrap-rtl.css');
      } else {
        //what should i do here????????????
      }
    }
  }
```

- So, when component first renders, `english` is selected. So, `isRTL is false`. As a result `require('........bootstrap-rtl.css')` doesn't come to play.
- Now, When I change language to `arabic`, `isRTL becomes true` and `bootstrap-rtl.css` is `required`. Now, I can see everything `rtl`.
- Now, when I again change language to `english`, `isRTL becomes false`, but `bootstrap-rtl.css` is not `unrequired`, so still I see everything `rtl`.

Can someone suggest me the solution or even alternate solution is acceptable for me.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [unloading code/modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6676612/unloading-code-modules)

Comment: I haven;t messed with React much, so i'm kinda guessing here. But when you inspect the page using your dev tools after switching to arabic, do you see a `<link>` to the stylesheet added? (More to the point, see what happens if you delete it.)

Comment: @Shadowfool sorry to say that the link you gave was already tried by me, but it does not work.

Comment: @cHao yes I see a link added to the head section of the document. If I delete it manually, rtl is gone and I get ltr. Thanks for the suggestion.  can you tell me what to do next?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Replacing css file on the fly (and apply the new style to the page)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19844545/replacing-css-file-on-the-fly-and-apply-the-new-style-to-the-page)

Comment: @gforce301 that does not contain anything about react. It has solutions using jquery.

Comment: @Vishal: My personal suggestion, if you want the ability to do both on the fly, is to use something like [bootstrap-rtl-ondemand](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-rtl-ondemand), and set the `dir` attribute on the `<html>` element as needed.

Comment: @cHao can you please provide an example of that?

Comment: @Vishal: After switching to the ondemand stuff, it looks to be as simple as `document.documentElement.dir = nextProps.isRTL ? 'rtl' : 'ltr';`.

Comment: @cHao I have tried to implement the code that you gave and I can now change dir attribute of html from ltr to rtl and vice-versa. But applied css always looks rtl. Can you please guide me on importing the css file as documentation suggests that I should import from a folder called bootstrap-rtl but the name of the package is bootstrap-rtl-ondemand and same is the case with bootstrap-rtl package.

Comment: @cHao I got it. I had to uninstall bootstrap-rtl and then install bootstrap-rtl-ondemand and then I had to reference the css file from bootstrap-rtl-ondemand folder from node_modules. Thanks man. Can you please post it as an answer? so that I can mark it as accepted and others in future may get help about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if there's anything special about how React `require`s stuff, but in general, loading a stylesheet basically means inserting a `<link>` element that refers to it. You can "unload" the stylesheet by removing the element that refers to it. You might also be able to disable it by setting its `rel` attribute to something besides "stylesheet".

But any change requires first finding that element. It's kinda messy.

If you want to be able to switch from RTL to LTR and back on the fly, there's a better way than "unloading" the RTL CSS. There's a fork of bootstrap-rtl called [bootstrap-rtl-ondemand](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bootstrap-rtl-ondemand) which, instead of *always* applying RTL styles, only applies them when the document's direction is set to "rtl".

Install the package above (or if you don't use NPM, get at least the CSS files from the package's Github repo), and set things up so that the CSS loads after Bootstrap's.

Now you can switch between RTL and LTR basically at will. Your method above becomes as simple as:

```
  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if (this.props.isRTL !== nextProps.isRTL) {
      document.documentElement.dir = (nextProps.isRTL) ? 'rtl' : 'ltr';
    }
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works beyond my imagination.

Comment: I'll leave the edit for others to decide on. My experience suggests to me that checking for changes before applying them wouldn't have a significant effect either way in a case like this, but as i've mentioned, i haven't messed with React much. :P

Comment: Good to hear from you. :)