# Stop/abort/terminate required (loaded) module

Tags: node.js, plugins, abort, worker-thread

Is there a possible way to stop/abort/terminate a required/loaded module?

I found here (https://stackoverflow.com/a/6677355/5781499) something:

```js
var name = require.resolve('moduleName');
delete require.cache[name];
```

But this does not stop/abort a running timer or similar.
It just keeps doing what the script does.

The reason for me to need this, I want to implement a plugin system where you can start & stop plugins.

"Starting" is easy, just load with `require(...)` the code.
But what would be the best way to stop everything the plugin is doing?

I have though about a VM, but in node there is no way to abort either a vm execution.
Next thing that came to my mind, was "Worker Threads". They provide a [`.terminate`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v14.x/docs/api/worker_threads.html#worker_threads_worker_terminate) method which does what I need. (But now I have to deal with inter process communication, which is very complex to keep everything synced)

Would be awesome if someone could give me a hint/tip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodejs does not provide any feature to do what you want so you will have to do a bunch of things manually.  As you've discovered, deleting the module for the module cache only affects what happens if you try to load the code again, it does not affect the already loaded code at all.

If you're going to keep the plug-ins in the same process, then you can implement a required method in your plug-ins called something like "shutdown" where the plug-in shuts itself down manually (stops timers, unregisters event handlers, etc...).  Implemented correctly, this should disconnect it entirely from anything in your nodejs program.  If you then delete the module from the require cache, you can then load a new module in its place.  The one downside to this is that nodejs does not ever unload the original code - it just stays in memory.  If you're not accessing that original module handle, that code never gets used again, but it isn't freed or GCed by nodejs.

A bit more robust system would be to put each plug-in in their own child-process or worker thread and just communicate with them via the built-in interprocess communication between parent and child process which is essentially just messaging.  As long as you don't have to send large amounts of data between parent and child/worker or have super high bandwidth data, then the messaging is pretty simple to use and works well.

If using a separate child process, you can then kill the child process at anytime and the OS will reclaim all resources used by the process (not quite so true for a workerThread).  This has its own downsides in that it will likely use a lot more memory since a whole new nodejs process or workerThread in nodejs is a much heavier weight thing than just loading a single module into your existing nodejs process.

Running it in a child process has the advantage that your main process is much more protected from errant code in the plug-in (either accidental or malicious) since they are different processes and the plug-in can't directly mess with the parent process.  But, don't fool yourself here, unless you run it in a sandboxed VM, the plug-in can still wreak some havoc on the system since it has access to many resources on the system (disk, network, other peripherals, etc...).